# SMARTY: ${ obj->render} doesn't render anything

Tags: php, smarty

I'm sending one of my object to smarty like

`$smarty->assign('test', new MyObject ) ;

....

$smarty->display('main.tpl');`

the MyObject class has a function called 'render' which returns a string representation of itself.

So in main.tpl I want to render this object like

`{$test->render()}`

Unfortunately it doesn't show anything in the HTML. Any suggestions how I can make this work ?

Thnx a lot
Jeanluca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$smarty->register_object()`.

Reference: [Smarty features: Objects](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/advanced.features.php#advanced.features.objects)

Comment: Thats what I need, thnx!

I just noticed that my code does work. Is register_object the preferred way when dealing with object?

Comment: @Jeanluca I don't know whether `register_object()` is better or worse than `assign_by_ref()`. In PHP 5, they shouldn't make a difference anyway (because object arguments get automatically passed by reference). If you want to make sure, for *huge* objects, maybe use `assign_by_ref()`.